# SHA 512 hashing and verifying

Tags: php, hash, sha512

Alright so Im trying to verify password with SHA 512, but no matter what it still returns false like the hash check is not correct.

Generating hash when registering

```
$hashed = password_hash(hash('sha512', $password), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

And to verify (upon login) I use simple

```
public function isValidLogin($username, $password) {
    $sql = $this->connect();
    $sql->real_escape_string($username);
    $sql->real_escape_string($password);

    $res = $sql->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE name='".$username."'");

    if ($res->num_rows >= 1) {
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            if (password_verify(hash('sha512', $password), $row['password'])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What you execly store in `password`? Everything looks good: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6be9bfccf7319332f6ca8faa5b6704f415d3d5e8

Comment: Does your database field has enough length for storing hash?

Comment: Well Im using 256 characters for the password

Comment: Make sure that value of `$hashed` is written to database completely.

Comment: Well I think is, Im getting 128 characters saved, this is how its saved

`9db2fda4438e3180bc3440b6ef52c98b58be9b657bf031f824bf9882d813f0c5b0ada477dad414ac188a758da49fc5236396652b0dc140a6629a62abcbe6b78b`

Comment: `$sql->real_escape_string($username); ` does nothing with the returned value.   You need to assign the result to something like `$username = $sql->real_escape_string($username);`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this code at time of registering instead of your code.

```
 $hashed = hash("sha512", $password);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// original password
$_password = 'bluebeans123';

$password = hash('sha512', $_password);
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

var_dump($password);

$verify = hash('sha512', $_password);
$verify = password_verify($verify, $password);

var_dump($verify);
```

Elaborate example: [http://wiki.travisfont.com/PHP:*Passwords*(hash_w/_SHA512)](http://wiki.travisfont.com/PHP:_Passwords_(hash_w/_SHA512))